# View State maintained through URL on page reload

Tags: visualforce, viewstate

I have delete link against the record on the visualforce page.When I click on delete link record gets deleted and then reloads the page successfully but view state is maintained in the url.I don't know how to remove this.

**View stateUrl** 
https://c.cs9.visual.force.com/apex/FC?com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF=DDJ0GM8ZVlS85i.RSAD.zXbq2770v0bY5Ypf3JQQI.j3VWgsnKQUR30SUBWmc3pyk8iF.xW2Ev49fvI7IY72CVu8bUX0Th6mxUcy3UJXlPdcOisfzgca39Va2H2t2AhgEbBwLEx6.g8voCONr_8IZRIQsqQ%3D&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion=201312112156340748&delMetricId=a2LK0000000QxpVMAS&id=a1DK000000wpLTsMAM&thePage%3AtheBlock%3Aj_id402%3Aj_id403=thePage%3AtheBlock%3Aj_id402%3Aj_id403&thePage%3AtheBlock%3Aj_id402%3Aj_id403%3Aj_id407%3A0%3Aj_id430=thePage%3AtheBlock%3Aj_id402%3Aj_id403%3Aj_id407%3A0%3Aj_id430

```
 public PageReference deleteProductMetrics(){
    String deleteMetricId= getParam('delMetricId');
       delMetric= [Select f.Id From FCR_Product_Metrics__c f where f.Id = :deleteMetricId];
       delete delMetric;
       pageReference del = new pageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
       del.setRedirect(true);
       return del;  
}



<apex:commandLink action="{!deleteProductMetrics}">Delete <apex:param name="delMetricId" value="{!c.id}"/></apex:commandLink>
```

Comment: When you say the viewstate is retained in the URL, what is it about this that is causing you an issue? Are you saying the record is still shown on the page? As I would expect some view state still to be present, even if its a new page.

Comment: current page url is not retained instead some viewstate url is added to existing page url.

Comment: Can you try ... pageReference del = ApexPages.currentPage(); del.setRedirect(true);

Comment: I suspect we are not really supposed to reuse the actually URL resulting from a commandLink. Other options would be to set 'del' to your actual page e.g. del = Page.myPage;

Comment: Or if it a a standard controller, del = standardController.getView();

Comment: But I am using same pagereference method from two different visualforce pages.So i cannot use del=page.mypage or del = standardController.getView(); as i have custom controller

Comment: Try... del = ApexPages.currentPage(); del.getParameters().clear(); del.setRedirect(true);

Comment: Its returning to the page but Id of record is deleting from url

Comment: Yeah you will likely have to add this back on Id id = del.getParmeters().get('Id'); del.getParemeters().clear(); del.getParmeters().put('Id', id); Its strange because the SF docs say setRedirect should clear view state, so my very first suggestion should work, if not i suspect its the use of commandLink perhaps.

Comment: Cool, which one did you use, my last suggestion?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Your last suggestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrew Fawcett  for his suggestions.So here is my solution.

```
 public PageReference deleteProductMetrics(){
    String deleteMetricId= getParam('delMetricId');
       delMetric= [Select f.Value__c, f.Product_Metric__c, f.Name, f.Id, f.Field_Coaching_Report__c,f.Field_Coaching_Report__r.Name From FCR_Product_Metrics__c f where f.Id = :deleteMetricId];
       delete delMetric;
       pageReference del = ApexPages.currentPage(); 
       Id id = del.getParameters().get('Id');
       del.getParameters().clear();
       del.getParameters().put('Id', id);  
       del.setRedirect(true);
       return del;  
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, does it still work if you remove  Id id = del.getParameters().get('Id');
       del.getParameters().clear();
       del.getParameters().put('Id', id);

Comment: As a note, the same worked for me without worry about the ID